# How to find out if DNS server responded with cached data?

Tags: dns

How do we find out that DNS responded with cached data rather than querying other DNS servers in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some difficulty. The only difference between from-cache data and from-authoritative data is that the TTL of the former will likely be lower than from the latter (if the data in the cache is less than a second old, the TTL can be the same in both cases). Of course, the only way to know for sure if the TTL is lower than from the source is to ask the source too and compare. However, the TTL set at the source will usually be an even multiple of 60 seconds, so it the TTL in the response you got isn't such an even multiple, the data likely came from a cache.

If you are trying to make this distinction and you are not writing a diagnostic tool for DNS, you are probably trying to solve the wrong problem.